# Web Application Rendering Methodology?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a Site Rendering Engine (well... ok, a CMS, with a bunch more...), that works extremely well.  I am, however, starting to think that I can make it more efficient.

Right now, the entire application renders the website through one /Default.aspx file, which takes in the Routing values, and renders the correct page.

What I am wondering is if I can get rid of that one page, and use a HttpHandler or HttpModule instead, would it make that initial load more efficient or not?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12614/discussion-between-o7th-web-design-and-asawyer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure enough! It'll result in performance improvement. Basically in ASP.NET page life cycle, HTTPModule and HTTPHandlers are anyway called by IIS to determine the types/extn of your files and then it reached your Default.aspx. And from there you are redirecting. If you can directly route your requests from layers above Default.aspx it'll improve the application performance. By the way, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335968/Implementing-HTTPHandler-and-HTTPModule-in-ASP-NET) is a great sample I found, Hope you enjoying tweaking your code.

Eagerly waiting for your results... please do share

Comment: Thanks.   Great article, and definately helped.   Wasn't much of a noticable speed difference, however, it was definately an improvement.